# Selenium webdriver - Safari > 16.x crashes after start up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

Selenium webdriver  - Safari > 16.x crashes after start up , in the our framework where we have lot of libraries - some of the few are cucumber ,testng , allure and reportportal.

Selenium-Java - 4.11.0
Safari > v16.x
JAVA OpenJDK 17

Out of our framework, Safari > v16.x works fine in an independent Java project. So the issue is some where within my framework , which is proving to be a hard nut to crack .

with in framework < v16.x works fine - the problems starts only with >v16.x. I dont see any stack trace - the only message i get is session doesn't exist - obviously as the safari crashes.

I have attached the crash dum from the Mac Os's - console - https://gist.github.com/deepakguna/ed60cd8163a75f3284164ddc420b137d

any thoughts to resolve this will be helpful.

This seems to be a strange issue and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue looks similar to the one we've recently faced with. Try this potential fix: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709225

Comment: If the link in your answer dies, then your answer is worthless. I suggest you add the crux of the link (i.e. disable the COOP header) to your answer - in addition to the link.

Comment: @Aisu Did you start facing this issue only after 15.3 ?